# I am getting the exception java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am using python and running some map reduce jobs. I am getting the below error only for one particular file, whereas other files with the same format is working just fine. I have looked into the file and it looks fine, there nothing different and when I run the map reduce python files locally on the data file, I dont get any error. Can someone please help me out.

```
2013-08-27 11:58:26,782 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskInProgress: Error from attempt_201308271128_0002_m_000000_0: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

Comment: I also tried adding #!/usr/bin/env python to both mapper and reducer files, it did not help

Comment: This is a generic error and it only means that either your python code is breaking somewhere or isn't being executed at all. Did you run locally on exact same input data? If not then it might be the corrupt input case. Also it might be a case of version difference, for me I had this error while the ruby code worked fine with 1.9.7, but on my cluster there was 1.8.7 so I was getting the same error as you.

Comment: Thanks Amar. I have ran it locally and it works fine and it fails around halfway through the MR job. There is a python version mismatch between by cluster and my local. Let me try updating the version and check.